# como cambio el is null en mi base de datos?

Tags: oracle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
necesito cambiar el null 
por los siguientes conceptos arrentario , dueño y representante legar pero me aparece un error en la linea 26 como la puedo corregir

Comment: Necesitamos un poco más de contexto para poderte ayudar, tu pregunta no queda muy clara.

Comment: Bienvenido Claudio Benavides a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Compartir el código en una imagen de toda tu pantalla hace muy difícil leerlo desde el móvil o si hay alguna discapacidad. Además, pone a la gente a transcribir el código desde una imagen, lo cual hace más demorado replicar tu error y responderte. Procura compartir tu código como texto siempre.

Comment: Tips para mejorar tu pregunta 1) corrige la etiqueta, imagino que estas hablando de `oracle` no? 2) no pegues una imagen, pega directamente el código que estás ejecutando y el mensaje de error como texto. Y por último, con `TIPO_PERSONA` en `NULL` solo puedes indicar un único valor posible, para llegar a completar arrentario , dueño y representante necesitas más información.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que te falta el END en tu CASE. También es un problema el hecho de que sólo se va a cumplir la primer condición y el resto nunca lo hará por lo que tienes código innecesario.